# Resource for practice data analytics projects

Tags: dataset

does anyone know of resources that offer data analytics/mining projects that I can tackle to help build my portfolio and present to interviewers?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a statistics question, but rather a data science one. Possible duplicate of the now closed question, which I have answered on the Data Science SE: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/843/2452.

Comment: Also, it's pointless, in my opinion. I wouldn't consider this type of "portfolio" seriously, unless you won some big competition. Mere participation counts for nothing.

Comment: @Aksakal: Not sure I agree with you. Of course, it's not a critical decision-making aid, but such "portfolio" could be helpful to both its owner and an interested party (for hiring or collaboration). For the owner's perspective, an implied open source portfolio by its nature will/might push the person to deliver better quality code (of course, provided that the person is the real author of the code). For the interested party's perspective, a presence of such portfolio will/might decrease the amount of time needed to assess the person's skills.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh, the only people with impressive open-source portfolios that I know, did not do it for the sake of portfolios, but for other reasons, usually as part of their regular jobs and consulting projects. It takes years to build such portfolios and gain credibility in open-source world, so as a job-search or resume-boosting tool this simply doesn't work, in my opinion.

Comment: @Aksakal: I understand. Maybe you're right in that regard. But, I still think that it could be useful motivational and benchmarking instrument for increasing and maintaining quality of code and responsibility of an author.

Comment: I just want something that i can talk about concretely during the interview to demonstrate my knowledge lol not necessarily a "grand portfolio" of amazing work